# Load in java chords of dynamic primefaces dragable components

Tags: java, primefaces, uirepeat

I am trying to load in java chords of dynamic primefaces dragable components.

My code has this look:

Primefaces

```
<ui:repeat   value="#{bbean.list}" var="dato">
  <h:panelGroup id="conpnl#{loop.index}"  layout="block">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{dato.desc}" />
    <p:selectOneMenu   id="datoCombo#{loop.index}">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
      <f:selectItems    value="#{dato.values}"  var="values"
      itemLabel="#{value.descripcion}" itemValue="#{value.codigo}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:draggable for="conpnl#{loop.index}" containment="parent"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>

<h:panelGroup>
 <p:commandButton id="saveChords" actionListener="#{bbean.saveChords}" 
 update="@form" oncomplete="client.setDirty(false);"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Java

```
public void saveChords() {

    UIComponent theContainer = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:tabs:j_idt199:0:datoCombo"); 
//This is dinamically how the browser has named the component (this is a test)

}
```

but i am not able to do it due these problems:
1)The java instruction FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:tabs:j_idt199:0:datoCombo"); 
doesn't retrieve any component, but this other one yes:
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:tabs:j_idt199:datoCombo");

How can i retrieve components defined dynamically inside ui:repeat?

2)If i could load the component in java side, how can i check its chords?